# Skip elements using xmlreader php

Tags: php, xmlreader, skip

I am using xmlReader to parse a large xml file (~100mb). Something like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <products>
        <product>
            <element_1>foo</element_1>
            <element_2>foo</element_2>
            <element_3>foo</element_3>
            <element_4>foo</element_4>
        </product>
        <product>
            <element_1>bar</element_1>
            <element_2>bar</element_2>
            <element_3>bar</element_3>
            <element_4>bar</element_4>
        </product>
        <product>
            <element_1>bar</element_1>
            <element_2>bar</element_2>
            <element_3>bar</element_3>
            <element_4>bar</element_4>
        </product>
        <product>
            <element_1>bar</element_1>
            <element_2>bar</element_2>
            <element_3>bar</element_3>
            <element_4>bar</element_4>
        </product>
        <product>
            <element_1>bar</element_1>
            <element_2>bar</element_2>
            <element_3>bar</element_3>
            <element_4>bar</element_4>
        </product>
    </products>
```

How do we skip the first 2  trees and move to the third one?

Comment: Skip the first 2 product trees* :)

Answer (score 0):

XMLReader goes through your file line by line. Since you don't have any identifiers (attributes) in your xml-file, you can only use a fix solution by skipping the product 1 and 2 by using "next()":

```
$xmlReader = new XMLReader;

// try to open
if (!$xmlReader->open($file)) {
    die("Failed to open file");
}

// read the file
while($xmlReader->read()) {

    // skip 1st product
    if($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == "product") {$xmlReader->next("product");}
    // skip 2nd product
    if($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == "product") {$xmlReader->next("product");}

    // start reading
    if($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->name == "product") {
        // use your code here

        // personally I like using simplexml from here since its easier to work with and the nodes are usually small enough
        $node = simplexml_load_string($xmlReader->readOuterXML());

        // use it
        $myNewElement1 = $node->element_1;
        $myNewElement2 = $node->element_2;
        $myNewElement3 = $node->element_3;
        $myNewElement4 = $node->element_4;
    }
}
```

Also go to http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.next.php